# dd command: Finding read/write throughput of a flash/SD?

Tags: io, dd, benchmark

I am running petalinux from sd card. And trying to find data copying rate  from Sd card and from QSPI flash that is there on the Xilinx Zynq board.

As suggested [here](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/QSPI-performance-under-Linux-is-very-disappointing/td-p/399901) , I am doing like this:

```
root@Xilinx-ZC702-14_7:/dev# echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
root@Xilinx-ZC702-14_7:/dev# dd if=/dev/mtd2 of=/dev/null bs=128k count=200
84+0 records in
84+0 records out
```

But as per the above link it should also print the following lines:

```
26214400 bytes (25.0MB) copied, 5.971374 seconds, 4.2MB/s
```

That gives an idea of rate at which flash working.

Why is this line missing in my case?
Is there any alterantive to know this rate ?

Comment: Haven't used petalinux before, but it looks like the type of distro that would use the BusyBox toolchain, which is really stripped down and might actually not do the progress notification.

Answer (score 2):

Showing the throughput rate is a feature of the version of `dd` from GNU coreutils which is found on non-embedded Linux. PetaLinux uses the [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/) utility suite, and its `dd` does not have this feature.

You can use the [`time`](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#time) utility to measure the total time, and divide the amount of data by that figure. Unfortunately BusyBox's `time` utility is cumbersome to parse.

```
bytes=$((128*200*1024))
time head -c $bytes 2>&1 |
awk -F '[^.0-9]+' -v bytes=$bytes '
    /^sys\t[0-9]*m [0-9.]*s$/ {
        sys_time = $1 * 60 + $2;
    }
    {print}
    END {printf "Throughput: %f MB/s\n", bytes / 1048576.0 / sys_time}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure `hdparm -T` / `hdparm -t` would work correctly on an SD card but it's worth trying.

Comment: it did not work in my case: root@Xilinx-ZC702-14_7:/dev# hdparm -T
-sh: hdparm: not found
root@Xilinx-ZC702-14_7:/dev# hdparm -t
-sh: hdparm: not found

Comment: Well install it first. It's quite standard, but usually not pre-installed.

Comment: this is not implemented for petalinux.

Comment: Embedded implementations are usually very limited. It's possible that this extra line of verbosity from `dd` isn't even implemented. gnu versions of core utilities are very extended compared to the bare standard. Do you have `time` available to directly measure the duration and then calculate it by yourself.